# Set useFunctionsEmulator(...) globally in iOS Firebase SDK in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Currently I use `functions.useFunctionsEmulator(origin: "http://localhost:5001")` to update the emulator link for every single invocation of `Functions.functions()` which means I could introduce errors. Is there a way to apply this setting globally for all firebase `Functions.functions()` call?

```
let functions = Functions.functions()
// Uncomment to hit local emulator.
// functions.useFunctionsEmulator(origin: "http://localhost:5001")
functions.httpsCallable("acceptParticipantRequest")
    .call([
        // params
    ]) { (result, error) in
        // handle results
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the existing documentation setting [useEmulator (or useFunctionsEmulator)](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/0322c1bda93b2885b995e3df2b63b48314546961/packages/functions/src/api/service.ts#L161) globally does not seem to be an option.

However, by calling this it will persist the settings within the FirebaseFunctions object. Thus, if you reuse the object, it will be persisted.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up writing an extension on `Functions`, see below code. Now if anyone has a way to have the compiler warn if someone directly uses `Functions.functions()` in my codebase, comment below.

```
extension Functions {
    /**
     * Use this to access Functions instance to avoid accidentally
     * leaving emulator wiring in prod.
     */
    static func sharedFunctions() -> Functions {
        let functions = Functions.functions()
        // Uncomment to use local emulator.
        //functions.useFunctionsEmulator(origin: "http://localhost:5001")
        return functions;
    }
}
```

And here is an example call:

```
Functions.sharedFunctions().httpsCallable("invite").call(...)
```